# How to load a pinyin.vim keymap in vim on Mavericks?

Tags: vim, keymapping

I am trying to get [this pinyin keymap](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/vim/vim-44/runtime/keymap/pinyin.vim) to load into vim.

I have placed this file into `~/.vim/keymap/pinyin.vim`.

**Questions**

1. How do I load this file automatically through a command in `~/.vimrc`?
2. How do I turn this mode on/off?
3. How do I actually invoke these keymappings?

**Answer**

[FDinoff's suggestion below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24522001/975129) is perfect.  What I did on **Mavericks** was update to [Snapshot 73 Vim 7.4.258](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/releases), `mv` the old `vim` to `/tmp` and `mv` `mvim` to `/usr/bin/mvim`, create a symbolic link and I was all set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This file is already part of the vim runtime so you don't need to include it yourself.

You can change what keymap you are using by using `set keymap=pinyin`. You can turn it off with `set keymap=`

To invoke the key mappings just type them literally in insert mode.

So for example typing `a2` will get you `á`

Take a look at `:h keycap` (Note this feature requires vim has been compiled with the keymap feature)

Comment: ty - this worked great in Ubuntu under vim 7.4, but fails in OSX under vim 7.3 - I suspect that the vim install on OSX somehow doesn't include that `pinyin.vim` file.  I'm trying to diff the installs to see what is going on...

Comment: @kfmfe04 just see if the file `$VIMRUNTIME/keymap/pinyin.vim` exists.

Comment: I just tried `:!echo $VIMRUNTIME` within vim and found that, indeed, pinyin.vim is missing for OSX.  After copying the file over to OSX, it still doesn't work.  Maybe I need to update some other `.vim` file?

Comment: @kfmfe04 is vim compiled with `keycap`? `echo has("keymap")` should return 1. Or check the output of `vim --version for `+keymap` (`-` means it is not compiled). If not you need to recompile vim.

Comment: that's it - tyvm - `:version` from within vim shows `-keymap` - I will look for the source and recompile it myself with keymap.

Comment: @kfmfe04 It might be faster to download macvim and use the version of that it comes with.